# How to install both ODAC 11.2 and 12.2 in a machine?

Tags: oracle, visual-studio, odp.net, odac, odt

I am working in different projects and one of my project is using Visual Studio 2010 and another one using VS 2017 and another one using 2015.

For `VS 2010` I have installed `ODACT with ODT 11.2` its working fine. But VS 2015 and 2017 needs `ODAC with ODT 12.2+` so I have installed 12.2 in my machine and there after VS 2010 solution edmx update is not at all working.

This is what the Visual Studio Activity log I am getting

```
 <record>330</record>
    <time>2019/04/03 08:11:41.598</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Begin package load [Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio]</description>
    <guid>{D601BB95-E404-4A8E-9F24-5C1A462426CE}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>331</record>
    <time>2019/04/03 08:11:41.598</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>CreateInstance failed for package [Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio]</description>
    <guid>{D601BB95-E404-4A8E-9F24-5C1A462426CE}</guid>
    <hr>80070002</hr>
    <errorinfo>Could not load file or assembly 'Oracle.VsDevTools.10.0, Version=4.112.3.20, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.</errorinfo>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>332</record>
    <time>2019/04/03 08:11:41.614</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>End package load [Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio]</description>
    <guid>{D601BB95-E404-4A8E-9F24-5C1A462426CE}</guid>
    <hr>80004005 - E_FAIL</hr>
    <errorinfo>Could not load file or assembly 'Oracle.VsDevTools.10.0, Version=4.112.3.20, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.</errorinfo>
  </entry>
  <entry>
```

I have tried couple of methods to fix this issue.

1. Used different oracle home for both installations
2. Removed `odp.net` related Policies from `GAC`.
3. Edited `machine.config` and changed the odac versions

But nothing is working.

Note : In Both installations I used machine wide installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install 12.2+ versions as non machine wide.

Move the `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client` to GAC.( Open VS 2010 command prompt as Run as administrator. then using gacutil -i "path to oracle managedaccess.client dll")

Then Open command prompt cd to the home directory path (odac 12.2 installed path). 
Example :

```
C:\app\client\Arunprasanth\product\12.1.0\client_1\odp.net\managed\x86>
```

Then run the following command

```
oraProvCfg.exe /action:config /product:odpm /frameworkversion:v4.0.30319 /productversion:4.121.2.0
```

Note : The above step will create an entry into your machine.config.

Now you can use ODT in both VS 2010 and 2015